# How to check alert is present or not continuously?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing Gmail unread mail counts, everything is working fine but due to slow internet I'm getting "Some feature cannot be load alert" how to handle this?

What my problem is: I need to check for the alert continuously because it can appear at any time, if it present then only i can able to dismiss it. Even if we use separate thread for to check alert is present like this

```
public void checkAlert() 
{
    try 
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       //exception handling
    }
}
```

also it won't work i think any idea!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Is it a standard javscript popup?

Answer (score 0):

I think GMail shown message in custom popup (actually it's div which looks like popup). Alert class can be used only with native java script popups.